# Windows STDERR redirection happening only on application exit

Tags: python, c++, windows, stdout, stderr

I have a c++ console application for which I am redirecting the output and the error streams to the file mentioned.

```
myapp.exe > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
```

The c++ application uses python module and the error is being generated by python module.

The problem is errors are being redirected to the file only on application exit.
No error is being logged to the file while the application is running.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How are your `std::err` being written, are they flushed correctly? ie. with `std::endl`?

Comment: comment python module and try generating errors from other modules.

Comment: Well i tried to write to stderr through c++
`fprintf(stderr, "Error");`

the error is being written only on application exit